# cannot multiply `&&EdwardsBasepointTable` by `&Scalar`

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, rust

I'm trying to build a custom pallet using the substrate-node-template, and when I run `cargo check` on the pallet, it's all good. But when I run `cargo check`  or `cargo build --release` on the whole node, I get this error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot multiply `&&EdwardsBasepointTable` by `&Scalar`
   --> /home/penay/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/snow-0.9.0/src/resolvers/default.rs:132:47
    |
132 |         let point = (&ED25519_BASEPOINT_TABLE * &self.privkey).to_montgomery();
    |                      ------------------------ ^ ------------- &Scalar
    |                      |
    |                      &&EdwardsBasepointTable
    |
help: `*` can be used on `&EdwardsBasepointTable` if you dereference the left-hand side
    |
132 |         let point = (*&ED25519_BASEPOINT_TABLE * &self.privkey).to_montgomery();
    |                      +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.
error: could not compile `snow` due to previous error
```

I have no clue what it may be, since it's not something I built or interacted with, at least not that I know of.

Comment: We are also seeing this build error in the CI. No idea yet what it is.

Comment: I just encountered the same error

Comment: https://github.com/mcginty/snow/issues/146 this an is upstream issue it seems

Answer (score 1):

I got this too.

Because I did the `cargo update` recently.

```sh
cargo update -p curve25519-dalek@4.0.0-rc.0 --precise 4.0.0-pre.5
```

Downgrading a specific package works for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for it https://github.com/mcginty/snow/issues/146
And few solutions PRs open
https://github.com/mcginty/snow/pull/147
https://github.com/mcginty/snow/pull/148